# Use beforeRouteLeave in Vue.js to trigger a quasar dialog confirmation windows

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

Hi guys i'm trying to create a mixin that allows me to open a quasar dialog window any time there's a form in my route/page AND the form has been modified.
This is what i got in my hands so far.

```
const inputHandler = {
  data() {
    return {
      isDirty: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    isDirty(newIsDirty) {
      if (newIsDirty) {
        window.alert("Wow, you're leaving with unsaved changes.");
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addChangeListenersToQForms() {
      const qForms = this.getQForms();
      qForms.forEach((form) => {
        form.addEventListener('change', this.onInputChange);
        console.log("addlistenertoqforms");
      });
    },
    removeChangeListenersFromQForms() {
      const qForms = this.getQForms();
      qForms.forEach((form) => {
        form.removeEventListener('change', this.onInputChange);
        console.log("removelistenertoqforms");
      });
    },
    getQForms() {
      const { container } = this.$refs;
      if (container) {
        return Array.from(container.getElementsByTagName('form'));
      }
      return [];
    },
    onInputChange() {
      this.isDirty = true;
      console.log('Form change');
    },
  },
};

export default inputHandler;
```

I haven't included the beforeRouteLeave logic yet but i'm getting the two console logs

the "removelistenertoqforms": when

only if I click back and forward on the browser. i tried to add the @change listener on every form present in my mainLayout and imported the mixin

```
import inputHandler from "src/mixins/inputHandler";

export default {
  name: "MainLayout",
  mixins: [mapper, inputHandler],
```

and added the main function to updated()

```
updated() {
    this.addChangeListenersToQForms();
```

anyway the message appears only the first time after i recharge the page and then i didn't manage to use the beforeRouteLeave (which by the way is not mandatory for me) .
all i need is a confirmation window any time i try to leave the page and the form has been modified .

Thanks for your help in advance